# Maven properties in gwt.xml

Tags: maven-2, gwt, properties, resources

How do I use a Maven properties from pom.xml in my.gwt.xml?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [Maven's Resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to replace wildcards in the xml file with settings in a properties file.

There are likely a dozen questions about resource filtering here if you need more information.

Comment: I've tried to do this to add a timestamp to the css file, but no matter how I use the resource filtering the wildcards is not replaced. I think the maven-googlewebtoolkit2-plugin overwrites the filtered file with an unfiltered version or the filter is not run at all... Have you actually made this work (with gwt)?